Why are green pair (or orange pair) wires not adjacent in RJ45 connectors?

For the sake of the discussion, let's talk about T-568B, but this applies to T-568A as well.
I've searched a bit for why the green cables are not adjacent, and the answer was that this reduces electromagnetic interference and crosstalk between wires.
Not coming from an electronics background, this is somewhat confusing to me.

I suppose the EMI happens along the cable, so the wires are in a twisted pair for interference to be canceled. What EMI is reduced by having this configuration only at the connector?

If separating pair wires is beneficial, why only the green pair? Why not have a configuration where no pair wires are adjacent (if possible)?

Regardless of whether it's beneficial or not, is it really that much of a deal? I mean, this is just the connector part. The signal has been traveling through meters along the cable, and I feel (probably wrong) that noise resulting at the connector can be negligible.



Legacy. Isn't it always.
For POTS (telephone) the RJ11 jack used a single pair in the middle.
The design of the jack series was such that as the number of pairs increased they would build out from the centre to allow smaller jacks to be connected to larger sockets and still pick up the required number of pairs. So for two POTS lines, the next pins out became the second line.
On RJ45 jack's used for ethernet connectors, the design was to allow existing RJ11 cables to be plugged in, meaning the two pairs 4/5 and 3/6 have to remain the same. This is actually fine for 10/100Mb ethernet so the design was acceptable.
As the number of pairs increases to support higher rates, pins 2/7 and 1/8 should have been the third and fourth pair. These are however too far apart to meet the differential signalling requirements. The existing split is not actually good for signal integrity on differential pairs at all.
So instead they cheated on the original design and instead put the two new pairs on 1/2 and 7/8 respectively to keep them close together. But legacy compatibility still meant the inner two pairs could not be easily changed, so the middle split stuck.
There's actually another pinout, ARJ45, where the middle two pairs were removed and instead placed on the top of the connector to allow them to be close together to support much higher data rates, whilst not breaking backwards compatibility.

So, if this separation has any effect, it will have a negative effect on the signal, and the best for the signals (regardless of compatibility) is to have them next to each other, right?

@OsamaAhmad yes, "kind of"! If I talk about differential signals, I usually consider the pair to carry one signal, not two signals. The actual place where the transport of energy, and thus information, between the source and the sink happens is the electrical field between the two conductors of a pair; so, in a pair, there's really no meaningful signal with only one conductor.

Also doing it this way would allow swapping a jack between single or double line POTS, or a similarly wired phone system, and Ethernet simply by punching down the wires differently in the wiring closet - i.e., get the order, change it in the wiring closet and then tell the user to plug in their phone (or computer) without having to change the jack between RJ11 and RJ45. Which is especially helpful if that jack is barely reachable behind a heavy bookcase or whatever, which Murphy's law seems to require.
